# Visual C++ : C2143

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64, office-addins

why would the following sniplet

```
#include <atlcom.h>
...
class FormRegionWrapper;
...
// Errorsource :
typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl
        <2, FormRegionWrapper, &__uuidof(FormRegionEvents)> 
        FormRegionEventSink;
```

will give me the following errors:

```
// Error ouput:     
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
             Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

?!?

(The sniplet is taken from here : [Building a C++ Add-in for Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee941475%28v=office.14%29.aspx) ). My environment : MS Visual Studio 2012 Professinal, and Windows 7-64.

PS 1:  Here what the help says about the IDispEventSimpleImpl :

```
// Help IDispEventSimpleImpl Class  : This class provides implementations of 
// the IDispatch methods, without getting type information from a type library.
//    template <
//      UINT nID,
//      class T,
//      const IID* pdiid
//    >
//    class ATL_NO_VTABLE IDispEventSimpleImpl :
//      public _IDispEventLocator<nID, pdiid>
//
// Requirements
// -------------------
// Header: atlcom.h
```

Comment: Why is it C2146 in your title but C2143 in the error output?

Comment: Unless `IDispEventSimpleImpl` is shown this is a useless question

Comment: C2143 in the error output, but I cannot edit the title, once entered... "Unless DispEventSimpleImpl is shown..." What do you want to see ?

Comment: Show the **usage** of this code. Most compiler errors are related to the context, not to type definitions.

Comment: I put the hyperlink with the usage...

Answer (score 1):

Have you included `atlcom.h` so that the template `IDispEventSimpleImpl` is defined? Are the declarations of other classes (I assume written by you)  used in the template declaration available? And i don't think that forward definition of `FormRegionWrapper` is enough, can you try and include the declaration of that class, so that template sees it?

**UPDATE**

Not sure if this will help much, but I replaced the source of `FormRegionWrapper.h` with the colde below (example from the MSDN page on `IDispEventSimpleImpl`:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

_ATL_FUNC_INFO Event1Info1 = { CC_CDECL, VT_EMPTY, 1, { VT_I4 } };

class CEventHandler;

typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl <1234, CEventHandler, &__uuidof(IDispatch)> 
DummySink;

class CEventHandler : public DummySink

{
public:
    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CEventHandler)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1234, __uuidof(IDispatch), 1, OnEvent1, &Event1Info1)
    END_SINK_MAP()
    void __stdcall  OnEvent1(LONG l)
    {
        //ATLASSERT(l == 445533);
        if (l != 445533)
            OutputDebugString(L"l is not 445533\n");
    }
    HRESULT Advise1234(IUnknown * punk) {
        return IDispEventSimpleImpl<1234, CEventHandler, &__uuidof(IDispatch)>::DispEventAdvise(punk);
    }
};
```

If this works, you can safely assume that the template is being included correctly.

Comment: Sure, atlcom.h is included... Its an example about an Outlook C++ AddIn Im trying to compile.

Comment: Updated the answer, I don't think that the forward definition of FormRegionWrapper is enough here.

Comment: No, there is the declaration of the class further down in the code ... I will put the rest ot the code also

Comment: If you define the class below the typedef the template does not see the class declaration, you must put it above the typedef.

Comment: The example is from here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee941475(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Just to note : The above is not an answer. I dont know who gave it a point.

Comment: I tried using the code from the example, but since i don't have the MS Office COM libraries needed by the example, i can't give much help.

Comment: Is there any simple redistributable/package that can be installed to get the libraries that are imported in `stdafx.h` ?

Comment: Unfortunanelty, no. At least not such that I know about. ATL files/templates come with Visual Studio Professional...

Comment: What would be a reason for the VC++ to have an include path towards the atlcom.h, and not to include it anyway ?

Comment: I don't think this is about `atlcom.h`, my initial question was about it, since it was not in the snipplet. If i replace the the `__uuidof(FormRegionEvents)` with `__uuidof(IDispatch)` and hide all the implemenations of methods in the example, the code compiles so I'm leaning towards that something is wrong with the way how the `FormRegionEvents` object is imported, but without the MS Office libraries I sadly can't answer.

Comment: I tried to replace __uuidof(FormRegionEvents) with __uuidof(IDispatch) but still the same compiler error. It seems to me that the for some reason the #include <atlcom.h> doesnt work, but on the other side, why would this be happening ... ?

Comment: Does you latest edit compile? I cannot compile it at the 1st line using atlcom.h ( _ATL_FUNC_INFO ...) the same error appears.

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine for me. Maybe there is an issue with the version of `atlcom.h`. Have you installed all VS updates? My `atlcom.h` is 169KB.

Comment: Well, that was my thought also a couple of days ago. So I reinstalled MS Visual Studio 2012 Professional. Forgot to mention that my OS is Win 7-64 (Maybe this is the clue). And the atlcom.h is 179 KB (183.859 Bytes) from 5.06.2012. Unfortunately it doesnt have an id. I also tried with the atlcom.h (175 KB) from MS Visual Studio 2010 Professional (Replacing the whole subfolder atlmfc in the VC folder), and the same error occurred. Is there a way to put your whole MS Solution folder for it?

Comment: PS Forgot to mention that the atlcom.h from the MS VS 2010 version is from 12.03.2010

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the #include directives in FormRegionWrapper.h:

using namespace ATL;